# Logitech c920 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Where to begin? Does it work? Anyone using it on Hangouts?

Tags: 12.04, webcam, logitech

I just got the Logitech c920 webcam for Christmas. I'm a little disappointed to read the different forum posts regarding the c920 and Ubuntu pairing. Ideally , I'd like to use this webcam on Google Hangouts, and I'd like to take advantage of the full 1080p HD capabilities.

However, I'm seeing that Hangouts is coded differently than Skype, and the webcam was spec'd with Skype in mind. Right now I'm looking at perhaps installing [GUVCview](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net)

Someone told me that using this in Hangouts will spike your CPU because "Google decided it was a good idea to abandon H.264 in favor of VP8/9 for video and audio encoding", and in order to get HD, you need 4Gb ram. I'm just looking for where to start? Haven't even opened the camera box yet, because I want to make sure this will work , or I'm returning it.

EDIT:  After running command below for installing GUVC this is the response I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l2' for regex 'libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l'
E: Unable to locate package v4l2loopback-utils
E: Unable to locate package gem-plugin-v4l2
E: Unable to locate package libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2'
E: Unable to locate package v4l2loopback-utils
E: Unable to locate package gambas2-gb-v4l
E: Unable to locate package gambas3-gb-v4l
E: Unable to locate package gem-plugin-dv4l
E: Unable to locate package gem-plugin-v4l2
E: Unable to locate package libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l'
E: Unable to locate package libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2'
E: Unable to locate package libv4l-ruby1.8
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libv4l-ruby1.8'
```

I'm running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Toshiba SatelliteL755

memory: 3.8 Gib

processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4

graphics: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile

OS-type 64bit

disk: 40.2 GB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GUVCview is one of the best applications available in ubuntu to Work with webcams.

It also provide drivers for webcams.

Not only WebCams but for HD Camcoders too.

It is better if you install V4L too. With that you can do lot of things with video devices.

If you want to install GUVCview run:

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

And for install V4L run this :

```
sudo apt-get install dov4l dv4l lib32v4l-0 libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l2 libv4l-0 libv4l-dev libv4lconvert0 libvideo-capture-v4l-perl qv4l2 v4l-conf v4l-utils v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-source v4l2ucp
```

Comment: Ok great.  After installing this through terminal, will GUVC application direct me through set up process? I never tried a webcam before.

Comment: I ran the command you provided me. I got some "unable to locate package" prompts. Could you take a look at the edit I made, and see if it looks right to you?

Comment: Ok thanks. It seems to have worked fine. I did get a pop up after installing V4L saying "System problem detected". But I have GUVC view, Video4 linux control panel and QTV4L2 test utility in my dashboard now. After installing these, how do I get the c920 to become the default webcam, as opposed to my built in laptop cam?  Sorry for all the questions, but my installation guide that came with camera is for Windows only.

Comment: That settings are told to be in `System`>`Preferences`>`Multimedia Selector`>`Video`. But I am on cinnamon. Can you try? System can be open by click on the Right end of the upper panel.

Comment: I can't find it. I tried different options under system settings, but I can't anything for video. I can select it in GUVCview, but I just wanted to see if that would remain as default. You helped me with my posted question. I consider it solved and I appreciate your help. THanks

Comment: I am on cinnamon desktop. I have to change to gnome to test and see. Will see and include in answer if I able to find.

Comment: Ok. Everytime I open GUVC, it opens with bad laptop cam. I can changeover fairly easily, but wondering how it would work if recieving video calls etc.

Comment: The package that handles it during the google video calls is `v4l2loopback-dkms`. Now you have already installed it. Try and see with skype.

Comment: I tried to make a video call with Google hangouts, and it automatically selects laptop cam, not c920.  I may just start another question thread. Thanks